# How do regular expression that accepts from 1 to 999?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate a field with `replace()`.
 For this, I need to accept values from 1 to 999. 
I've tried the following regular expression but it does not work because it does not support `"10"` or `"100"`
Regex: `/[^1-9]/g`

Code:

```
function fromUser(text) {
                if (text) {
                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^1-9]/g, '');

                    if (transformedInput.length > 3) {
                        transformedInput = text.substring(0, 3);
                    }

                    if (transformedInput !== text) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                }
                return undefined;
            }
```

I need to admit the values between 1 and 999.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The purpose of `regex` is to verify the format, not the values. You can check your input against `/\d{1,3}/` (1-3 digits) then use `parseInt()` to get a number and compare it against the limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with an expression like `^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$`:

```js
let str = "1002113320400";

isValidNumber = str => !!str.match(/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$/);

console.log(isValidNumber("0")); //false
console.log(isValidNumber("00")); //false
console.log(isValidNumber("000")); //false
console.log(isValidNumber("9990")); //false
console.log(isValidNumber("10")); //true
console.log(isValidNumber("100")); //true
console.log(isValidNumber("999")); //true
```

Comment: I try using the following: 
`Var transformInput = text.replace (/^ ( [1-9] | [1-9] [0-9] | [1-9] [0-9] [0-9]) $ /,' ');` and it does not work, it has the opposite behavior.
How can I deny the expression? Thank you

Comment: remove the spaces,

Comment: `let transormInput = text.replace(/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$/, ' ');` is what you will want to use

Comment: I made an example with your solution for my problem.
What I need is that you only accept numbers from 1 to 999, but with your solution, the opposite happens. :/ 
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/inactivity/8vpdgwcu/30/

Comment: @Cristian take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/ltsOver9000/2ev0dbqc/3/ . Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Exactly. I appreciate it a lot. Thanks!